# How can I properly restart a ViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, storyboard

I'm making a game on the iphone and the problem that I am having is that when I attempt to restart a viewcontroller, there is still data running through it but I want the viewcontroller to completely stop running my codes, what I've done is invalidating all the nstimers, nilling all the images, but there is still data, so when I try clicking restart IBaction to go to another viewcontroller the game is still running in the background even though I switched to the homescreen,  it just stacks up making my game slow... This is what I did but it's probably improper way to kill the viewcontroller process because there's data coming out even though I'm killing everything that is suppose to function within the storyboard...

```
-(IBAction)restartandsave {

    [moveenemy invalidate];
    [moveenemy2 invalidate];
    [iup invalidate];
    [idown invalidate];
    [invisibleTimer invalidate];

    immune = nil;
    enemy = nil;
    enemy2 = nil;
    barrierground = nil;
    barrier = nil;

    if (kills > highscore)
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:kills forKey:@"highscore"];
        congratz.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Congratulation, you reached a highscore."];
        }  
}
```

Comment: I don't know want do you means but if you go in your first controller all the other controller are release automatically and if you reset all the global variable is like to have a new start

Comment: Short simple story: I want to COMPLETELY kill a story board when I tap "restart" but it just stacks up the storyboard when I attempt to go back to the storyboard

Comment: Do you really mean "storyboard"? I think your talking about view controllers, or "scenes" as each controller is called in a storyboard.

Comment: Yea sort of... If I dont invalidate all my nstimers and nil everything, I could still hear the game running in the background when I switch a storyboard.. how would I be able to kill everything in the storyboard without invalidating or nilling... I believe it's improper coding..

Comment: What do you mean, "yea sort of"? Do you have multiple storyboard files (files ending in .storyboard) or not? If not, don't call them storyboards, it's both confusing and wrong.

Comment: I have 3 view controllers, yea that's what I mean...

Comment: You should edit your question to make it more clear. Take out the erroneous references to storyboards, and describe what controllers you have, how you go back and forth between them, and which one you're trying to "restart".

Comment: Hope it's clear now...

Comment: No, it's still far from clear to me. I still don't know what 3 controllers you have, and how they relate to each other. Which is on screen first? How do you get from the first to the second, and the second to the third? How do you go back, and from which controller and to which controller? Which of the 3 are you trying to reset?

Comment: I have 3 controllers, 1 is home screen which has links to 2 viewcontrollers which is "highscores" and "play". The first Viewcontroller that pops up is obviously the home screen. When clicking "play" the game launches. With in the "play" viewcontroller there is a button to restart the game so that it goes back to the home screen, however if I tap the "restart" button, the game goes back to the homescreen BUT the game is still running. Even if I invalidate everything and nil everything the game is still considered running, the only view controller I'm trying to reset is the "play" viewcontroller